# Disable damage cam animation for 1.20

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I am a server developer for my friend's server, I use 1.20.1 for the server because the mods work better, my friend said to change to 1.19 because of the damage animation, It's on SpigotMC, I tried to find plugins that remove damage animation, but its for Fabric (The mod is [**Sodium Extra**](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/sodium-extra)) but it needs to be on SpigotMC, Please help me.